# are the following css styles are valid

Tags: css

I am reading a Responsive website book, where I see the styles definition like

```
.main-navigation 
  {
    li {position: relative;}
    .children 
          {
            left: -999em;
            position:absolute;
          }
   }
```

I have also tried in my css file, but seems not to be working. 
Now my question :) Can we define css style in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not proper CSS. But you can use this with a CSS preprocessor like [less](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules).

Quote from the website:

> Rather than constructing long selector names to specify inheritance, in Less you can simply nest selectors inside other selectors. This makes inheritance clear and style sheets shorter.

This works with [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/), too.